# Why am I losing portions of my command line arguments? PHP/shell_exec

Tags: python, php, cmd

I have a PHP script that takes data that is a 'JSON ready' string and passes that through a command line via shell_exec to the Windows OS command line. On the other end (which is a python script) I gather the argument via sys.argv and for debugging purposes I print the argument to a simple .txt file. When I inspect the file I notice that roughly the last half of my argument from the PHP script is missing. I initially thought after doing some digging that perhaps I was exceeding some sort of character limit either in PHP shell_exec's function or the command line itself. My research came to this page from Microsoft: [Command prompt (Cmd. exe) command-line string limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-client/shell-experience/command-line-string-limitation) that states the command line has a character limit of 2047 characters.

I was hopeful that this was going to be my problem as I could work around it but unfortunately my command string only has 1730 characters total.

I know I can either chunk the arguments and send the chunks individually over, or save the argument as a file and have my python script pick it up that way, but if I am within the operating parameters of the command line, in a sense that this 'should' work then I'd prefer to utilize this method. Not to mention that I am working in a windows environment now for our Dev version of our application but production gets pushed to a Linux server (I hate this but unfortunately I don't have control of these factors). And on our production Linux distribution it works and utilizes this command line processes.

Here is my command line code:

```
$cmd = "python C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\app\\pages\\plot\\python\\plotfunction.py " .$data;
$output = shell_exec($cmd .' 2>&1 &');
```

And $data is a json-like string that contains 1653 characters.

The python that reads the sys.argv is this:

```
ATP_CHART_SPEC_json = sys.argv[1].replace("$", '"')
```

And when I save ATP_CHART_SPEC_json to a file it contains only 750 characters. I'm losing a little more than half of my argument.

NOTE:

The .replace in python was used by me to overcome the issue that apparently when sending a string as an argument over the command line (or for some other reason I am not aware of) I lose all of my '"' characters which when they're escaped using "" in python becomes a problem. So temporarily in PHP I replace all quotes with $ and replace them back after the transfer. I've verified this does not (usually) damage the integrity of the JSON string.

Comment: You may be able to use the [`shlex.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) utility to get valid command-line arguments.

Comment: I could be wrong but I do not believe the argument itself is invalid. As far as I can tell there are no characters or symbols that would cause any escapes or misinterpretations of the argument. I thought about posting it in my question but wasn't sure if that would be appropriate with how long it is?

Comment: I suggest you try it and see if you're right—it shouldn't be that difficult to do.

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve].